# Google Chrome is not displaying javascript updates (using Three.js)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

I'm following along with this youTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axGQAMqsxdw to create a POV game. I got to episode 8 of the tutorial, then google chrome began showing a white screen no matter what I changed in the javascript. There are no warnings or problems when inspecting the code with chrome's developer tools either.

I've tried to start from scratch with completely new files. I've cleared the caches for chrome. I've double checked the source code with my altered code, but none of my alterations seem like they would cause a problem (I am new to javascript though, so that could be a problem). Below is the newly started js file based 100% off the youTube tutorial.

```
var scene, camera, renderer, mesh;

function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x8CD9FF );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (90, 1280/720, 0.1, 10);


    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({color: 0xff9999, wireframe: true})
        );

    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(1280/720);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    animate();
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);



    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Maybe [these tutorials](https://threejsfundamentals.org) would be helpful for you

Comment: These will definitely help me out, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the THREE documentation concerning renderer size [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setSize).
You need to set width and height pixels and not the ratio, so try to replace `renderer.setSize(1280/720);` with `renderer.setSize(1280, 720)`